# Differentiating $\arcsin(x)$ using first principle method.

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

**Q.** Differentiate $\sin^{-1}(x)$ using first principle (delta) method.

I did this the following way:

$$y=\sin^{-1}(x)$$

$$\therefore\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{h\to \:0\:}\left(\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(x+h\right)-\sin^{-1}x}{h}\right)$$

Now let

$$\sin^{-1}(x+h)=A\text{ and }\sin^{-1}(x)=B$$

or

$$x+h=\sin A\text{ and }x=\sin B$$

$$\therefore h=\sin A-\sin B$$

∴ When $h\to \:0\:$ ,

$$\sin A\to \sin B\text{ or }A\to B\text{ or }A-B\to 0\tag 1$$

$$\therefore\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{A-B\to \:\:0\:}\left(\frac{A-B}{\sin A-\sin B}\right)$$

## $=\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{A-B\to 0}\left(\frac{A-B}{2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}\right)$

## $\:\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{A-B\to \:\:0\:}\left(\frac{2}{2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)\frac{\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}{\frac{A-B}{2}}}\right)$

## $\:\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{A-B\to \:\:\:0\:}\left(\frac{2}{2\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)}\right)$

as ($\:\frac{dy}{dx}=\lim_{A-B\to 0\:}\frac{\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)}{\frac{A-B}{2}}=1$)

## $\frac{dy}{dx}=\left(\frac{2}{2\cos\left(\frac{2B}{2}\right)}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{2\cos\left(\sin^{-1}x\right)}\right)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2\:}}$

The final answer is valid. But is this method correct? Is **EQ.1** correct? Or is it just a fluke. (It seems to work for all other inverse functions too).

Comment: Yes, EQ.1 is correct. It expresses the continuity of the function $\sin$.

Comment: So, shouldn't we consider the general solution of sine ($n\pi +\left(-1\right)^n\theta $)??

Comment: For a rigorous approach, you need to specify which branch of the $\arcsin$ you use to make it univocal.

Comment: It's correct, but it's so much easier to use the inverse function differentiation rule $$f\prime^{-1}(x)=\frac{1}{f\prime(f^{-1}(x))}$$